# Unable to connect to WSUS and Group Policy

Tags: windows, networking, group-policy, wsus

So I have an odd issue where my server is unable to connect to either my WSUS server or update Group Policy.  While running updates I noticed that one of my servers errors saying it can't connect to the WSUS server (my own, not MS).  I rebooted several times and removed and re-added it to the domain and checked the network properties, still not able to connect to WSUS.  It was last able to connect to WSUS a month ago.

I'm able to ping the WSUS server from this machine though.  The other odd thing was I decided to run a gpupdate and I got an error with that as well.  I can ping the domain controller though and I'm remoted into this machine to manage it so clearly its able to contact the DC and is working with DNS.  Funnily enough I decided to check the Windows Firewall and I can't make changes to it because it's managed by group policy...which I can't update from??

Any idea what would be causing me to be unable to connect to WSUS or GP but still seems to be working properly on the network otherwise?

This is Windows Server 2016 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out the issue by trying to open local security policy and getting an error.  Apparently the local .pol file was corrupted.  By renaming that and re-running gpupdate it succeeded and was able to get the right WSUS settings from GP.